# How to show that $X_n\to0$ in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ independent random variables, with $P(X_n=n)=1/{n^2}$ and $P(X_n=1/n)=1-1/{n^2}$ . Show that $X_n\to0$ in probability.

I got this problem in an old probability test but I'm not sure how to use the definition of convergence in probability:

$X_n\to X$ in probability, if $$P(\omega \in \Omega | \lim_{n\to \infty}X_n(\omega))=1$$

p.s.: I'm using Sheldon Ross' book "*A First Course in Probability*", but it doesn't have a convergece topic. Is there a better book?

Comment: There must be a typo with the statement $P(X_n=1-1/{n^2})$

Comment: There was, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We say that $X_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability if $$P ( X_n \geq \epsilon) \rightarrow 0$$ for every $\epsilon$.

So fix any $\epsilon$.

Pick $N$ so that $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$, then for $n \geq N$ can you find a bound on the probability that $X_n \geq \epsilon$?